# Update new column with data from csv file

Tags: sql, postgresql, csv

I have a postgres table called `users_user` with a new, and empty column, called `uuid_unsubscribe`.

Now I have a csv file with 420 uuids, one for each user.

**uuids.csv**

```
e0af0a31-3eb3-43d5-9d3d-xxx
e0af0a31-3eb3-43d5-9d3d-yyy
e0af0a31-3eb3-43d5-9d3d-zzz
....
```

My question is, how to update this table, specifically add a new uuid for each user from that file? I want to avoid one manual update for each row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to import the CSV file of UUID values and assign each row a unique identifier that can be matched with the primary key of your `users_user` table, then update `users_user` from the joined imported table.

Here's one approach to do that.

Import the CSV file--assume that the imported file is named `imported_uuids` and the column containing the UUID values is named `uuid`.

Add a temporary sequence column to the `users_user` table.

```
alter table users_user
add column seq bigint;

update users_user as a
set seq = rn
from (select user_key_column, row_number() over() as rn from users_user) as x
where x.user_key_column=a.user_key_column;
```

Assign a similar set of `seq` values to the imported UUID values and run the update:

```
update users_user as a
set uuid_unsubscribe = n.uuid
from (select row_number() over() as seq, uuid from imported_uuids) as n
where n.seq = a.seq;
```

Clean up.

```
alter table users_user
drop column seq;
```

If your `users_user` table already has a column that contains a 1-based sequence of numeric values without gaps, you could use that instead of adding the `seq` column as done in this illustration.

Comment: This seems complicated. I think that I will export all users_id, then just concatenate in excel and create an update query for each user.

Comment: Alternatively, if you have control over your Postgres installation, so that you can install extensions, the `uuid_ossp` and `pgcrypto` extensions both contain functions that will generate UUIDs within Postgres.  You could use those in a single UPDATE statement.

Comment: yes I have. How can I do that using a single command with uuid_ossp?

Comment: Just `update users_user set uuid_unsubscribe = uuid_generate_v4();`